# Trying to keep user loggedIn in my android app after first login but not working

Tags: android, authentication, sharedpreferences

I am developing an android app, my app have a login activity. What i want to do is once a user is logged in for the first time it will remain logged in even if the app is closed.

I tried a way out but it didn't worked well.
Any help will b appreciated.
Thanks!

1) Login.java

```
private Snackbar snackbar;
private ProgressDialog pd;
private TextInputLayout mTiEmail;
private TextInputLayout mTiPassword;
private CompositeSubscription mSubscriptions;
private SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;
private Boolean loggedIn = false;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    mSubscriptions = new CompositeSubscription();
    mSubscriptions = new CompositeSubscription();

    loginUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email_edit);
    loginPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pass_edit);
    pd = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
    mTiEmail = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.email1);
    mTiPassword = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.password);
    loginButton = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
    initSharedPreferences();
    loginButton.setOnClickListener(view -> login());

    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        //In onresume fetching value from sharedpreference
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Constants.SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        //Fetching the boolean value form sharedpreferences
        loggedIn = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(Constants.LOGGEDIN_SHARED_PREF, false);

        //If we will get true
        if (loggedIn) {
            //We will start the Profile Activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, Dashboard.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
private void initSharedPreferences() {

    mSharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Login.this);
}
private void login() {

    setError();

    String email = loginUserName.getText().toString();
    String password = loginPassword.getText().toString();

    int err = 0;

    if (!validateEmail(email)) {

        err++;
        mTiEmail.setError("Email should be valid !");
    }

    if (!validateFields(password)) {

        err++;
        mTiPassword.setError("Password should not be empty !");
    }

    if (err == 0) {

        loginProcess(email,password);


    } else {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Enter valid details", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
private void setError() {

    loginUserName.setError(null);
    loginPassword.setError(null);
}
private void loginProcess(String email, String password) {

    mSubscriptions.add(NetworkUtil.getRetrofit(email,password).login()
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(this::handleResponse,this::handleError));
}
private void handleResponse(Response response) {

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mSharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(Constants.TOKEN,response.getToken());
    editor.putString(Constants.EMAIL,response.getMessage());
    editor.apply();

   loginUserName.setText(null);
    loginPassword.setText(null);
    Intent in = new Intent(Login.this,Dashboard.class);
    startActivity(in);
    Toast.makeText(this, "REGISTERED-->>", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
private void handleError(Throwable error) {


    if (error instanceof HttpException) {

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

        try {

            String errorBody = ((HttpException) error).response().errorBody().string();
            Response response = gson.fromJson(errorBody,Response.class);
            Toast.makeText(this, response.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {

        Toast.makeText(this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}


}
```

Here in my onResume() method i tried a way out but didn't work, Any Suggestions?

2) Constants.java

```
public class Constants {

public static final String BASE_URL = "http://192.168.2.145:8080/api/v1/";
public static final String TOKEN = "token";
public static final String EMAIL = "email";
//This would be the name of our shared preferences
public static final String SHARED_PREF_NAME = "myloginapp";

//This would be used to store the email of current logged in user
public static final String EMAIL_SHARED_PREF = "email";

//We will use this to store the boolean in sharedpreference to track user is loggedin or not
public static final String LOGGEDIN_SHARED_PREF = "loggedin";
```

}

**UPDATE**

Login.java

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView loginButton;
EditText loginUserName, loginPassword;

private Snackbar snackbar;
private ProgressDialog pd;
private TextInputLayout mTiEmail;
private TextInputLayout mTiPassword;
private CompositeSubscription mSubscriptions;
private SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;
private Boolean loggedIn = false;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    mSubscriptions = new CompositeSubscription();
    mSubscriptions = new CompositeSubscription();

    loginUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email_edit);
    loginPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pass_edit);
    pd = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
    mTiEmail = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.email1);
    mTiPassword = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.password);
    loginButton = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
    initSharedPreferences();
    loginButton.setOnClickListener(view -> login());

    }
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    //In onresume fetching value from sharedpreference
    mSharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("login", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if(mSharedPreferences.getBoolean("LoggedIn", false)){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this,Dashboard.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else {
        loginButton.setOnClickListener(view -> login());

        //Do other stuff
    }
}
private void initSharedPreferences() {

    mSharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Login.this);
}
private void login() {



    String username = loginUserName.getText().toString();
    String password = loginPassword.getText().toString();

    loginProcess(username,password);


    int err = 0;

    if (!validateFields(username)&& !validateFields(password)) {

        err++;
        mTiEmail.setError("Username should not be empty !");
    }



    if (err == 0) {

        loginProcess(username,password);


    } else {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Enter valid details", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


}

private void loginProcess(String username,String password){

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    RetrofitInterface requestInterface = retrofit.create(RetrofitInterface.class);

    User user = new User();
    user.setUsername(username);
    user.setPassword(password);
    ServerRequest request = new ServerRequest();
    request.setOperation(Constants.LOGIN_OPERATION);
    request.setUser(user);
    Call<ServerResponse> response = requestInterface.operation(request);





    response.enqueue(new Callback<ServerResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ServerResponse> call, retrofit2.Response<ServerResponse> response) {
            if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                ServerResponse serverResponse = response.body();
                if(serverResponse.getMessage().equals(Constants.SUCCESS)) {
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mSharedPreferences.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("LoggedIn",true);
                    //editor.putString(Constants.EMAIL,serverResponse.getUser().getEmail());
                    editor.putString(Constants.USERNAME,serverResponse.getUser().getUsername());
                    editor.putString(Constants.BUSINESSNAME,serverResponse.getUser().getBusinessname());
                    editor.apply();



                    Toast.makeText(Login.this, response.body().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    goToProfile();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(Login.this, serverResponse.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } else {
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                ServerResponse errorResponse = null;
                try {
                    errorResponse = gson.fromJson(response.errorBody().string(), ServerResponse.class);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Toast.makeText(Login.this, errorResponse.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ServerResponse> call, Throwable t) {


            Log.d(Constants.TAG,"failed");
            Toast.makeText(Login.this,t.getLocalizedMessage() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}



private void goToProfile(){

    Intent intent = new Intent(this,Dashboard.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

Comment: Where are you saving preferences? The first thing you need to do is when you log in/sign up save a boolean value in your shared preferences. On the consecutive visit, just fetch that value. Invalidate that value when the user logs out.

Comment: @Waterbyte yes, i think i am not saving my preferences, can you tell me how to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code in your onCreate()

```
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPrefrences("login", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); //Opening 'login' sharedPreference 
if(pref.getBoolean("LoggedIn", false)){ //checking if 'LoggedIn' exist in SharedPreference if no exist it returns false. if it exist fetches its value
   //Move to Next Screen
} else {
   loginButton.setOnClickListener(view -> login());
   //Do other stuff
}
```

**Then in your handleResponse().. Add these lines**

```
//Lets suppose if User is logging in for the First time.. Below lines will add 'LoggedIn' to shared preference so user logged in directly next time

   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
   editor.putBoolean("LoggedIn", true);
   editor.apply();
```

Comment: you again brother :D , well it worked but what is happening is that if i commented the code the login screen will appear and then without logging in i again insert the code and build my app again then my Dashboard actvity is appearing not my login activity

Comment: SharedPreferences keeps data .. until you clear data from setting or uninstall app.

Comment: i didn't applied anything you told in handleResponse() but it is still working

Comment: clear your app data and try again. if it stops on login screen then code is working fine. Otherwise there's something wrong. you have to save LoggedIn (boolean) in your SharedPreferences to keep track of User logged in.

Comment: it is reacting weirdly, I cleared all data then started the app again login screen appears then without logging in i pressed home button after that i started it again and takes me to the dashboard ...this is really weird.

Comment: bcz you have placed code at wrong place. Read comments in Updated Answer. If you still have probelm. tell me

Comment: Add Editor and below 3 lines in **HandleResponse** bcz it is putting LoggedIn to true..

Comment: okay okay, it is working now i added an extra line. After cleaning the code it is working fine.

Comment: i already have an editor in handlereponse , only need to add putBoolean which i added already.

Comment: Okay that's great, If it helps you. add it as accepted answer. **Happy coding!**

Comment: hey, that time it worked very well but i changed some of my code and again used this method to keep user logged but it is not working....if you want i will add the new code

Comment: Yeah sure.. Edit it. Or post another question

Comment: What problems you're facing now

Answer (score 0):

Set `LOGGEDIN_SHARED_PREF` in your `void handleResponse()` as below :

```
editor.putBoolean(Constants.LOGGEDIN_SHARED_PREF,true);
```

Set your sharedPreferences globally

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Constants.SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

And edit on the same in your `handleReponse()`

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
```

I updated your code:

```
private Snackbar snackbar;
private ProgressDialog pd;
private TextInputLayout mTiEmail;
private TextInputLayout mTiPassword;
private CompositeSubscription mSubscriptions;
private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
private Boolean loggedIn = false;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    mSubscriptions = new CompositeSubscription();
    mSubscriptions = new CompositeSubscription();

    loginUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email_edit);
    loginPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pass_edit);
    pd = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
    mTiEmail = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.email1);
    mTiPassword = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.password);
    loginButton = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.btn_login);

    loginButton.setOnClickListener(view -> login());

    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        //In onresume fetching value from sharedpreference
        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Constants.SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        //Fetching the boolean value form sharedpreferences
        loggedIn = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(Constants.LOGGEDIN_SHARED_PREF, false);

        //If we will get true
        if (loggedIn) {
            //We will start the Profile Activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, Dashboard.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

private void login() {

    setError();

    String email = loginUserName.getText().toString();
    String password = loginPassword.getText().toString();

    int err = 0;

    if (!validateEmail(email)) {

        err++;
        mTiEmail.setError("Email should be valid !");
    }

    if (!validateFields(password)) {

        err++;
        mTiPassword.setError("Password should not be empty !");
    }

    if (err == 0) {

        loginProcess(email,password);


    } else {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Enter valid details", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
private void setError() {

    loginUserName.setError(null);
    loginPassword.setError(null);
}
private void loginProcess(String email, String password) {

    mSubscriptions.add(NetworkUtil.getRetrofit(email,password).login()
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(this::handleResponse,this::handleError));
}
private void handleResponse(Response response) {

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(Constants.TOKEN,response.getToken());
    editor.putString(Constants.EMAIL,response.getMessage());
    editor.putBoolean(Constants.LOGGEDIN_SHARED_PREF,true);
    editor.apply();

   loginUserName.setText(null);
    loginPassword.setText(null);
    Intent in = new Intent(Login.this,Dashboard.class);
    startActivity(in);
    Toast.makeText(this, "REGISTERED-->>", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
private void handleError(Throwable error) {


    if (error instanceof HttpException) {

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

        try {

            String errorBody = ((HttpException) error).response().errorBody().string();
            Response response = gson.fromJson(errorBody,Response.class);
            Toast.makeText(this, response.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {

        Toast.makeText(this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}


}
```

Comment: Proceed. Any roadblock let me know :)

Comment: naah ! didn't worked, i logged in then i removed my app from mobile stack and opened it again still login screen opens

Comment: Oh. You are getting from one preference whereas you saved to another.

Comment: maybe , i got confused :D

Comment: Did you got it?

Comment: Thank you for your response, but another method worked for me.

Comment: but i will try this method too.